# Alternative definition o a well order

Tags: order-theory, well-orders

Can we define a well ordered set just like a totally ordered set having the least element?

Namely, is the statement *"the toset **T** has the least element"* equivalent to *"any non empty subset of the toset **T** has the least element"*?

Regards.

Comment: Pick a totally ordered set without a least element, add an apple, and declare the apple to be the least element. You obtain a new total order with a least element, of which the original set is a subset without a least element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are not equivalent.

The non-negative reals $[0,\infty)$ with the usual ordering have a least element (namely $0$) but are not well-ordered because the subset $(1,2)$ *does not* contain a least element.